# Moving data outside of the scope my jQuery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little AJAX function that asks the server whether a particular checkbox should be checked. I'd like to pass the information to a variable outside of the scope of the AJAX function. Something along the lines of:

```
isChecked = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/subscribe-query/",
                data: "selfKey=" + commentData['selfKeyValue'],
                success: function(isSubscribed){
                    if(isSubscribed == 'true'){
                        return = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        return = false;
                    }
                }
            })
```

or

```
var isChecked; 
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/subscribe-query/",
                data: "selfKey=" + commentData['selfKeyValue'],
                success: function(isSubscribed){
                    if(isSubscribed == 'true'){
                        isChecked = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        isChecked = false;
                    }
                }
            })
```

Neither of those works of course. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var isChecked; 
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/subscribe-query/",
                data: "selfKey=" + commentData['selfKeyValue'],
                success: function(isSubscribed){
                    if(isSubscribed == 'true'){
                        isChecked = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        isChecked = false;
                    }
                }
            });
alert('isChecked');
```

in this code even if the 'isChecked' property is set properly in the ajax success function the alert will say `undefined` because the ajax call is `Asynchronous`. It will raise the alert before the ajax success function returns. Therefore you need to do your work after the ajax success function like this. You can pass the variable to do the work after ajax success.

```
           $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax/subscribe-query/",
                    data: "selfKey=" + commentData['selfKeyValue'],
                    success: function(isSubscribed){
                        chek(isChecked);//pass the variable here
                    }
                });


  function chek(isChecked){
     if(isChecked){
         $('#YourCheckbox').attr('checked','checked')
     }
     else{
         $('#YourCheckbox').removeAttr('checked')
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Clear explanation and example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating an object that has an isChecked property. That's safer than using a simple global variable. For example:

```
var inputObj = {};
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/subscribe-query/",
                data: "selfKey=" + commentData['selfKeyValue'],
                success: function(isSubscribed){
                    if(isSubscribed == 'true'){
                        inputObj.isChecked = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        inputObj.isChecked = false;
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: That's barely safer; if you're advocating safety, the state would be encapsulated within an actual module. Along with that, move the comparison into something reusable as well since the rest of the system would likely use the same return methodology. It makes the entire `success` callback disappear into the app-specific JS code, and is *actually* safe, rather than just nudging the problem one level deeper.

Comment: It actually is in an object (I paired the example down some), and the whole thing is happening inside a larger function. The problem though is that, in the code above, if I log `isChecked` outside of `$.ajax({})` it's `undefined`, even though inside `$.ajax({})` it has the correct value (true/false).

Comment: @Dave -- of course your proposal is safer. But truly eliminating global variables in JavaScript can take some work, and depending on your site that extra work is unnecessary.